# Improve Lines Detection Using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image like

[image]

and I would like to detect most of the lines in the image. I am using HoughLines function in OpenCV.

The code looks like:

```py
src_img = cv.imread("./snapshot_0711.png")

gray_img = cv.cvtColor(src_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel_size = 5
blur_img = cv.GaussianBlur(gray_img, (kernel_size, kernel_size),0)

dst_img = cv.Canny(blur_img, 100, 250, None, 3)

cv.imshow("dt", dst_img)

lines = cv.HoughLines(dst_img, 1, np.pi * 1 / 180, 100, None, 0, 0)
```

It detected many lines, but the results (first case) is not satisfactory, like:
[image: First Case]
Is there anything doing wrong in my code? Will I need a preprocessing?

Using the `LineSegmentDetector` recommended by @Micka, the result looks like (second case):
[image: Second Case]

I want to improve the first case. In the case output, is there way(s) connecting the small segments?

Thanks.

Comment: The lines you see are not really straight lines. `HoughLines` is not really a function for this case. Since your lines are almost horizontal/vertical, you can erode in separate direction (Canny uses both), and extract the horizontal lines separately from the vertical lines.

Comment: Try LineSegmentDetector, which is quite sophisticated

Comment: @Micka, linesegmentdector works nicely. But how could I connect the small segments into a polyline?

Comment: probably from line direction and segment-endoint distances and a graph-based matching, but will be some algorhtm- and implementation-work.